# Why do comments only come through on 2 of my posts and not the others?

Tags: comments

Good day.  I have posted 88 posts, however, comments only come through on 2 of the older posts. Why is this happening? It is really frustrating.

Comment: Check that you don't have unapproved comments. Also check that comments aren't blog by some kind of spam filter. It is really impossible to tell what the exact fault can be without knowing exactly how your comments are setup and how you are displaying them.

Comment: Thank you Pieter.  I have different spam filters.  How would you be able to see how my comments are setup in order to assist with my problem? I will look at the mini markdown formatting, and see if this helps and I don't have unapproved commments.  My blog site is called :  lifetotell.com Many thanks!

Comment: This is unfortunately a hands on job that is out off scope of this site. Best will be is to deactivate plugin by plugin and doing tests after each plugin to find out which plugin is causing the problems. Also switch to a default theme and do some tests